# collapsing two columns in one in sql?

Tags: sql

Say I have a table like that:

```
|x1|y1|

|0 |1 |

|2 |4 |

|3 |2 |
```

I know I can do something like that:

```
SELECT a.x1 AS .., a.y1 AS .., 
       b.x1 AS .., b.y1 AS .., 
       c.x1 AS .., c.y1 AS .., 
       d.x1 AS .., d.y1 AS .. 
FROM xytable a, xytable b, xytable c, xytable d 
WHERE ...
```

In my result table, however, I would like to output a.x1 and a.y1 together, as a a tuple under *one* column. In other words, I want to have:

```
|c1          |c2            |c3             |c4           |

(a.x1, a.y1) | (a.x2, a.y2) |  (a.x3, a.y3) | (a.x4, a.y4)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Tell us what variant of SQL you're using: SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: This question is unclear.  Perhaps a table of input/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a character string?

You can do something like

```
SELECT '(' + convert(varchar, x1) + ',' + convert(varchar, y1) + ')' as "col"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL, you could use the `CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT('(', a.x1, ', ', a.y1, ')') AS c1
FROM 
    xytable a, xytable b, xytable c, xytable d 
WHERE 
    ...
```

In SQL Server, you can concatenate with the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT 
    '(' + a.x1 + ', ' + a.y1 + ')' AS c1
FROM 
    xytable a, xytable b, xytable c, xytable d 
WHERE 
    ...
```